PID with on-off controls: optimize pwm duration
I am doing a DIY project to keep an oven around 25 Celsius degrees to make some bread. The first version uses hysteresis controls, but the overshot due to inertia is huge, the temperature goes up to 45 degrees once I stop at 25 degrees.
I was therefore planning to combine hysteresis control with PID, controlling a quite long PWM cycle as explained in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/can-a-pid-controller-have-a-simple-on-off-output.
Issue: if the length of the duty cycle is fixed, I feel this will be sub-optimal. Too short and it will damage quickly my magnetic relay and create extra noise (the relay is quite noisy, I should maybe consider SSR/zero-cross opto-triac… but this seems to be quite big). Too long and it will likely take too much time to adapt to changes.
So is there an elegant solution to converge to an optimal PWM period ? I don't want to hardcode it for two reasons:

the optimal duration may not be stable over time. E.g. it may be better to have a short duration when the system starts and increase it when the system starts to stabilize.
my device may be used with a wide range of ovens/heating mechanisms (maybe I can just put some strong lights in a small box and it will be enough to reach 25 degrees…), and I ideally don't want to recalibrate it every time I go to a new heating device (or there should be some automatic calibration procedure)

EDIT
I plotted here the time/temperature curve (time in mn in x axis, temperature in Celsius degrees, y axis), for an hysteresis that starts to heat when the temperature drops below 24 degrees (green line) and stops when the temperature goes above 26 degrees (blue line):

So basically, it heats during 30s and it is good for 23mn ^^ There is a lot of hot inertia, very little cold one. If we compute how much power is needed here on average to maintain a steady temperature (i.e. the power of the loss due to the oven non-perfect insulation), this gives:
$$P_{\text{loss}} = \frac{1500 \times 30}{23 \times 60} = 33 \text{ Watts}$$
Here, I just put a bit of water in the oven, but I couldn't see how temperature was evolving inside. I plan to add a second thermometer inside to record both evolutions.
Curious to see what would happen if I put a smaller hysteresis (e.g. 0.5°C degrees instead of 2°C)
EDIT 2
For the fun, I added a second thermometer to record the temperature of a bowl of 300ml of water, with the same (largely overshooting) hysteresis 24-26°. Well, that's fairly interesting: even with a strong overshoot, it takes 1h to heat 300g of water to 25°! And then, it goes above 26°, due to the overshoot. I don't know if it is the best idea to control only the external temperature only, unless I pre-heat the sourdouh/bread I may put inside. In picture (the time on x axis is in mn):

If I assume again that the oven is 1500W as claimed (but this is again an approximation based on the datasheet of the oven), since a period is 21mn and it takes 38s to heat, this gives as expected a higher power estimation of 44W on average. But now I need to heat quicker since waiting 1h to gain a few degrees for only 300g is too long…

PWM regulating a relay is going to kill that relay in no time, plus it is bad for EMC purposes as you noticed. SSR sounds more suitable indeed.

Why not use high power resistors like https://se.rs-online.com/web/p/chassis-mount-resistors/2634242. Then regulate them using current, which can still be obtained from PWM. It's also possible that something based on PTC thermistors would work.

What kind of time constants are we looking at? Both heating and cooling.

@MOSFET in term of heating, it takes make 40s to heat from 19 degrees to 26 degrees, but with the inertia after maybe 2mn it arrives to 45 degrees. The cooling is slower, maybe 10mn to go down to 26 degrees, but I need to do more precise measurements.

@Lundin how would you power this? Directly from 230v or would I need some transformator to turn it to xV? Seems anyway lot's of work compared to using an existing oven and I'd like to avoid playing too much with high currents for safety reasons, and I still need some sort of relay in the end anyway, so the same question still applies to save the life of the relay.

@Lundin if the pwd has a period of maybe 10-60s woild it also kill it this fast?

45°C is nothing so you don't need a lot of current, we're talking DC and mA. However there might be health aspects/regulations regarding placing electronic components together with food that I'm not aware of. But it will respond much faster. And just using some thermostat which cuts the power at a certain temperature will do, no need for PID, no need for relays, no need for VAC. I've used that very solution plenty of times for keeping electronics warm and dry.

What are the amps/watts of the oven? It's 230V, right?

@MOSFET It's 1500W (student oven), so around 6.5A at 230V (my relay is 10A so should be good enough).

@Lundin Thanks, but I'm confused about the DC/mA here. If we want to have 150W (which does not seem so absurd, I still want to heat maybe 2Kg of dough in a reasonable time…), even at 24VDC we need 6.25A, which is not that negligible… As I understand, the precise resistor you sent is 1.5Ohms, so to get 150W we need 15V/10A, which is out of reach of any arduino. Am I missing something? Do you think I don't need 150W in practice? How would you recommend to obtain his power?

@tobiasBora I just linked a random resistor for the purpose of showing the mechanical part. You don't need 150W, where does that number come from? You need a certain temperature. With a power resistor, all of the energy is transformed to heat so it is very efficient. In the past I've heated "small oven sized" electronics boxes up to some 50-60°C with a thermostat and maybe 24V over 25 ohm or so for roughly 1A current draw. The power needs to come from a 24V supply. What does Arduino have to do with anything? Just buy a thermostat product.

@Lundin ok thanks, maybe 150W is not required, but I did the following computation: I have 2kg of dough (say mostly watter), with a thermal capacity of 4.19J/g/degrees. If the dough is 17° and must go to 26° this is +9°, so the total energy needed just to increase the temperature is J = 4.19*2000*9. If I want to do that in, say, T = 10mn = 10 * 60s, then the power required is W = J/T= 126W, so close enough to 150W if you consider the loss. But in practice, I do pre-heat the dough with hot water, so I may not need that much power, but hard to tell how much loss my oven has…but worth a try

@tobiasBora That calculation assumes that all the energy is going to heat the dough, uniformly throughout its mass at a consistent rate, when in fact you'll be heating the air in the oven which will then heat the dough, from the outside in.

@LordTeddy sure, but the energy still need to come from somewhere, irrespective of whether I'm heating directly to dough or the air first. Hence, I'm doing an under-estimation here since the air will also heat the container etc… My point is that 150W does not appear to be a crazy expectation to me. Or am I missing something?

@tobiasBora but you're not going to able to pump 150W into the dough. The rate that heat enters the dough is a function of the difference between the dough temp and the air temp. You can't increase the air temp beyond the desired 26° else the dough will be too hot on the outside. The yeast will also heat the dough, and might well get it slightly warmer than the oven.
Besides, when rising dough, it's not about getting the internal temperature to a desired value, it's measured in the volume of changing. As long as the dough is in a warm spot, the yeast does the rest.

@LordTeddy But do you agree that I'm going to pump at least 75420J into the dough (unless I pre-heat it)? The exact power depends on the time I need to wait until the dough reaches equilibrium, so if I assume equilibrium after 10mn, then I do need 150W, but indeed, if I assume that equilibrium will take more time (not absurd), I may indeed require a lower power, like if equilibrium is reached after 30mn, I only need 41W (assuming no loss). In my edit, I computed the oven-loss to ~33W, so I need roughly 73W to compensate loss + heat the dough in 30mn.

@LordTeddy Regarding the volume of the dough, this is maybe how you know sourdough is ready, but it definitely needs some extra help to maintain the temperature so yeast can work. I tried before to let it in my kitchen… nothing happens basically until I put it in a 26° place, then the sourdough can double size. Hence my project.

@tobiasBora I think you're overthinking this, and exactly how much energy you put into the dough isn't what matters, what matters is creating a warm box for it to sit in while it rises. Trying to calculate the required power based on the mass of the dough isn't relevant because a) the internal temperature of the dough isn't critical, and could well rise above the box temperature and b) the actual math behind what temperature the dough reaches is far too complicated to do. I would get going with whatever you've got and not stress about it.

Your oven is extremely over powered to do this properly. But you can PID this with a mechanical relay by scaling the gain way down - something like 3%-5% duty cycle as the full scale. And a PWM frequency of 100mHz. Based on your 33W assumption, steady-state should be 220ms on time for the relay with a 10 second period.

@MOSFET yeah, that's why I wanted to increase the cycle, like do 2x220ms every 20s to save a bit the relay, at least when it reach a stable curve. Maybe I can just manually check how stable the temperature is and increase it manually when it is in a fuzzy-logic fashion ^^

If you are up to programming, then a µP (such as the Arduino) for control might be a good solution.
PID loops can be complicated and difficult to implement, so I suggest using Fuzzy Logic control.
In Fuzzy Logic the main loop is just a series of If-Then-Else statements, whose functions are generally easier to understand than that of a PID program, and thus easier to tweak the program to get the desired results. Also Fuzzy Logic more readily handles non-linear system response, whereas PID assumes a linear system.
A Fuzzy Logic program is written the way a (fast) human operator might tweak knobs or switches to control a system (in your case, turning the heater on and off at the experimentally determined appropriate time and duration to maintain the temperature).  Such a program can be designed to handle different ovens/heating elements (It may not be optimum for every one, but should still be able to arrive at a stable temperature).  For example it could measure how fast the temperature is rising/falling, and then use that to adjust the on/off periods as it gets near the set point.
Here's an article on Fuzzy Logic, if interested.

Thanks, I'll read in more details. I already use an arduino to read the temperature sensor/switch the relay, so it is not a problem. The only thing I don't love about fuzzy logic is that it seems quite approximate compared to PID (and in the end to see how fast the signal moves, we still need some sort of derivative computation etc), but I'm curious to see how they compare. I was actually thinking to mix PID and fuzzy logic by increasing the PWM duration so that the temperature does not move in this time interval, and reduce it when it does. Let's experiment!

Fuzzy logic is only approximate to the level of precision you do the calculations (which would also be true for PID done with a micro).  The derivative computation to see how fast it moves is simple delta temp / delta time (not complicated).  In the past I suggested fuzzy logic to a poster who was trying to control a Cappuccino machine and was having problems trying to get his PID program to control the temperature and water pressure properly.  He then replied that his first attempt at a fuzzy logic program worked better then the PID loop he had been working on for weeks.

Ok good to know! I'll try to read to read about fuzzy logic, thanks!

In answer to your original question, there probably is a method to converge to an optimal PWM length but you probably don't want to do it.
You effectively want to find the longest PWM period (to maximise the life of the relay) while still being able to get adequate control of the heating (which would be better the shorter the period is). 
Doing this manually you might increase the period until the control starts to degrade. You might also have to tweak the PID values as this happens. You could make it a little easier by having a range of acceptable solutions - ie a maximum permissible overshoot, maximum time to temperature, and a minimum acceptable lifetime for the relay. 
Could this be automated? Sure, but instead of just writing a simple PID control system, you'd also have to write a bunch of software to be able to change the PID and period values. Assuming you wanted to do something faster than just running all the possible combinations, you also need a method to decide how to change all the variables. This represents a lot of time, code, and dough. 
My first reflow oven, I made from a toaster oven, and Arduino and a magnetic relay worked well enough with a magnetic relay. I think my period was somewhere around ~5s, I replaced it for code reasons, the relay never broke. Bottom line is if you've already got the relay and parts, you could just get it working and if it works then wait for it to break until you fix it.
The better option is to use a solid-state relay, which my current oven uses. You can have a much smaller period, which results in a much smoother response.
I can't imagine that it would be very practical to write a one-size-fits-all PID loop to work with any given heating element for the same reasons as before. It can be done, but unless you end up using quite a sizable array of different heaters, I think it would be more efficient to tweak the PID for each one individually.
